# busyboxにコマンドを追加したい

Tags: linux, command-line

busyboxに自作のコマンドを追加したいです。

下記のサイトを参考にしながら進めています。

[BusyBoxを拡張してアプレットを追加する方法【前編】](https://monoist.itmedia.co.jp/mn/articles/0902/03/news118.html)

記事ではversion 1.9.0なのですが、僕の環境ではうまくできなかったのでversion 1.27.0のbusyboxで動かしています。

問題点としては、

> （b）「include/applets.h」を修正し、＜アプレット名＞_main関数を登録する

この部分が僕のbusyboxでは存在しません。その代わりIF_から始まるコードが存在します。

```
IF_MICROCOM(APPLET(microcom, BB_DIR_USR_BIN, BB_SUID_DROP))
IF_MT(APPLET(mt, BB_DIR_BIN, BB_SUID_DROP))
IF_NANDWRITE(APPLET(nandwrite, BB_DIR_USR_SBIN, BB_SUID_DROP))
IF_NANDDUMP(APPLET_ODDNAME(nanddump, nandwrite, BB_DIR_USR_SBIN, BB_SUID_DROP, $
IF_PARTPROBE(APPLET(partprobe, BB_DIR_USR_SBIN, BB_SUID_DROP))
IF_RAIDAUTORUN(APPLET(raidautorun, BB_DIR_SBIN, BB_SUID_DROP))
IF_READAHEAD(APPLET(readahead, BB_DIR_USR_SBIN, BB_SUID_DROP))
```

なので記事の方では

```
USE_MTD_DEBUG(APPLET(mtd_debug, _BB_DIR_SBIN, _BB_SUID_NEVER))
```

となっているものを

```
IF_MTD_DEBUG(APPLET(mtd_debug, _BB_DIR_SBIN, _BB_SUID_DROP))
```

と変えて追加、実行しましたがアプレットが見つからないといわれます。

```
./busybox mtd_debug
mtd_debug: applet not found
```

さらに、先ほど変更したはずのinclude/applets.hを見てみると変更が反映されていません。
実行前は確かに変更が反映されていましたが、makeの後make installをすると

```
IF_MTD_DEBUG(APPLET(mtd_debug, _BB_DIR_SBIN, _BB_SUID_DROP))
```

がなくなっています。

どのようにすれば自作コマンドを追加できるのでしょうか？

Comment: (追加情報？として) BusyBox取得したら `docs/new-applet-HOWTO.txt` というファイルが含まれているはずなので, 参考にできます。よ (少なくとも昔のサイト参照するより)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
読んでみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v1.36.1 で動作する最低限の例です。

`miscutils/hello.c`（追加するファイル）:

```c
/* vi: set sw=4 ts=4: */

//config:config HELLO
//config:   bool "hello (?? kb)"
//config:   default y
//config:   help
//config:   print hello message.

//applet:IF_HELLO(APPLET(hello, BB_DIR_USR_BIN, BB_SUID_DROP))

//kbuild:lib-$(CONFIG_HELLO) += hello.o

//usage:#define hello_trivial_usage NOUSAGE_STR
//usage:#define hello_full_usage ""

#include "libbb.h"

int hello_main(int argc, char **argv) MAIN_EXTERNALLY_VISIBLE;
int hello_main(int argc UNUSED_PARAM, char **argv)
{
    puts("hello world!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

ビルド:

```bash
make menuconfig
make
```

実行:

```shell
$ ./busybox hello
hello world!
```

---

`include/applets.h` は冒頭に、

```c
/* DO NOT EDIT. This file is generated from applets.src.h */
```

とある通り、`make menuconfig` で生成されるものですので、直接編集することはありません。[FAQ](https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#adding)に従い既存のアプレットを参考にして、適切なコメント（`config:` など）が含まれたソースコードを追加すればよいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

手元のコードを見ると、編集するなと書いてありました。
コメントもよく見ないといけないと再認識できました。